# How to automatically import Include in Code Blocks like in Eclipse Java?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

If it's impossible to do like that in Code Blocks. Then: for example I'm in exam and I know method memcpy(), but I forgot in which include it's. Can I somehow read stack trace to find it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing in `man function` in the terminal should tell you what library to include.

**EDIT** : Trying saving an empty project with only the headers and use this project file to type in your code.

**EDIT 2** : Trying `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. This will include all the standard libraries. You no longer have to remember every library names (all though, I never use this practically).

Comment: Where can I find terminal?

Comment: It should be in the launcher/applications menu. Which OS are you using?

Comment: W7, 64 bit. Sorry for late reply, but can't seem to find it: http://prntscr.com/eo9i3j

Comment: Terminal is native to Linux (well, Windows 10 has bash!). I edited my answer which might help you.